# Cant get object from @Input

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have **system.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let tab of tabs | async">
  <app-tab [tab]="tab"></app-tab>
</div>
```

Code in **tab.component.ts**

```
export class TabComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() tab: Tab;

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.tab);
  }  

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

With **tab.component.html**

```
<mat-tab label="{{ tab.name }}"></mat-tab>
```

I got 3 *undefined* in console, and 0 tabs in angularMaterial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place it inside ngOnInit  instead of inside constructor, Input isn't initialized until view is set up. constructor gets called before that

```
constructor() {

}  

ngOnInit() {
 console.log(this.tab);
}
```

Comment: As your are using the `async` pipe, be careful that your tabs are initialized on time, otherwise you may need to implement `OnChanges`